# Do you run yeoman/gruntjs inside your vagrant (vm)

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, yeoman

So I want to start using yeoman (Gruntjs/requirejs/bower), but I was wondering if this could be done from inside your vm or would it be better for my workflow to have it installed on my host machine (OSX)? As far as I know you need to have a couple dependancies like node.js.

Is this a subjective thing or is there a guideline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @matt-cooper said, it's a subjective thing.

Personally, I run it on my host because that's where git and my IDE live and I consider Yeoman etc to be development tools that belong outside the backend code, whereas inside my VM I expect it to reflect my deployment server which doesn't need to meet the same requirements as Yeoman.

Comment: I know that this is subjective, but isn't the purpose of Vagrant to manage development environments? I can see the argument for Scaffolding tools like yo to be outside, but not so sure about grunt and bower.

Comment: In all the cases I use Vagrant, it's more to control the server side development aspects - The way Apache is setup, make sure the right modules are included, support libraries are in the correct place etc.

Where as Grunt et al focus on uncompiled code, so as long as their resulting files pass tests, I don't care so much about how they got there.

I've also found, this helps when working with people with different IDE and OSes preferences, as there is a clear separation between development tools, and the server side deliverables.

Comment: My confusion over this is because I generally use grunt to start a nodejs server instead of Apache.

Comment: At the end I chose to install nodejs both locally and within the VM. The main reason I use the local version is because CodeRunner uses it for running JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

This is purely a subjective thing... you can do either.

If you are only ever going to use one VM then you could install grunt etc on the VM or the host and use it, it would mean that you would have to ssh into the VM each time you wanted to run grunt commands though.

If however you are going to have more than one VM setup then you might be better to have grunt etc. installed on your host machine rather than having to maintain multiple versions.