# Yeoman Permission issue in vagrant when installed globally

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vps, yeoman

Today I started with exploring yeoman. I am using Vagrant with a clean Ubuntu 12.04 box. The box is provisioned using this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Ilyes512/7458072) that I created and update with the steps I am performing inside vagrant.

So I have installed node globally. When I create a new map `~/yo-demo && cd yo-demo` and then type `yo` I get to see yeoman. But I try to install a generator I get a error:

`[Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp']`

This is because node_modules is not vagrant's but it's a root (user) folder. So I can fix this with `sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /usr/lib/node_modules`. But I am not sure if this is the best thing to do.

Is there another way of fixing this? I think I could install it locally, but then again I can't use the `yo` command from within any folder (That's what I read, but not sure? I havent tested it).

I am soon going to have a VPS and while I wont install yo on there I would probably install other things like node. What would be the preferred location on a vps? Locally or globally?

Comment: Personally I run Yeoman from the host system, not inside the VM. But, rather than change ownership of the directory, how does doing 'sudo npm install -g generator-webapp' work?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that and that does indeed work, but then you can't use the nice 'yo'-ui. For instance you can search and see the generator's and but can't install it that way. And about running yeoman on host. Yeah, already asked about that as well :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790726/do-you-run-yeoman-grunjs-inside-your-vagrant-vm For now I am still fooling(/testing/playing) around. So a VM is perfect for that. edit: ow, you are 1 of the 2 that answered me :) hehe